# Log out 1 specific user out of X users in my Application

Tags: asp.net, authentication, logout

I am trying to create a method that I can pass a username to and that method will logout that user if that current user is logged in. Can someone point me in the right direction to go. I am doing this in ASP.NET

Comment: Do you want to logout the user from other account like Admin account ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [SignOut](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.signout.aspx) method to signout the current user:

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // if a user is authenticated kill the authentication cookie:
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    // make sure you redirect in order for the cookie to not be sent
    // on subsequent request
    Response.Redirect("~/default.aspx");
}
```

As far as signing out another user is concerned, authentication cookies wouldn't be enough. You will need to store on your sever (probably a database) a list of authenticated users, then customize the forms authentication and check whether the current username is in the connected users table and only then allow him to login. When signining out you will need to remove the user from that table.

Comment: I need to log a specific person out. That only works for a specific browser.

Comment: I need to be able to go through all users and log out the ones that I want.

Comment: @Robert, you will need to change the way you are tracking authenticated users if you want to achieve that. As I said in my answer you will need to persist a list of authenticated users on your server. The forms authentication provider by default only uses cookies which are stored on client browsers and you cannot modify other clients from within a given request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Membership method FindUsersByName.

According to Scottgu, if you  were to **change the role** of a user the user would get kicked out on the next request if you did not have caching turned on.

I cannot think of another way to log out a user since you do not have access to their FormsAuthentication ticket.